# Замена параметров на Edit Delphi

Tags: delphi

Как в приведенном ниже коде, заменить число **+12** и число **+1** на **Edit4** и **Edit5** (К примеру). Чтобы можно было задавать параметры в **Edit** а не программно?

```
while (Pos(Edit2.text,s) > 0) and (Pos(Edit3.text,s) > 0) do
  Delete(s, Pos(Edit2.text,s), Pos(Edit3.text,s)+12-Pos(Edit2.text,s)+1);
```

Comment: `Возможно ли` - да, возможно :)

Comment: Подскажите как сделать ? :).

Comment: Вам нужен не сам Edit1, 2...180, а его содержимое. Содержимое находится в поле EditX.Text. Оно строковое. Для преобразования в число есть функции StrToInt, а лучше - StrToIntDef. Всё, задача решена. Это обобщенное описание конкретизируете под свои Edit-ы (подставляя преобразования вместо этих 12 и 1), оформляете ответ и получаете профит :)

Comment: Вот это да :). Мне еще учить и учить. Благодаря Вам вопрос решила и сделала ответ на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Благодаря пользователю kami, вопрос решен:

```
while (Pos(Edit2.text,s) > 0) and (Pos(Edit3.text,s) > 0) do
  Delete(s, Pos(Edit2.text,s), Pos(Edit3.text,s)+StrToInt(edit4.Text)-Pos(Edit2.text,s)+StrToInt(edit5.Text));
```

Comment: StrToIntDef избавит вас от ошибки "невозможно преобразовать строку в число", если в edit4.Text будет абракадабра вместо числа. Если кроме чисел в этих полях ввода ничего не должно появляться - лучше использовать SpinEdit. Тогда и StrToInt не понадобится - есть свойство SpinEdit.Value, которое сразу числовое.

Comment: Очень полезный совет, у себя в коде переделала под  SpinEdit. Благодарна Вам от чистого сердца.