# Перевод значений из Edit в Random Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Возможно ли вывести значения через edit в коде (То есть заменить число 25 на Edit):

```
for j:=0 to len-1 do baze:=filtr+Dict[Random(25)+1];
```

То есть что бы было типа:

```
 for j:=0 to len-1 do Pass:=Pass+Dict[Random(edit1.text)+1]; // Но тут я не знаю как правильно оформить, **потому как ошибка**.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, подобного рода вопросы Вы задаете часто. Постарайтесь подходить к этому логически.
1. В `Edit1` Вы вводите текст, значит вероятнее всего в поле `Text` строковое значение.
2. `Random` выбирает случайное число, значит параметром нужно передать числовое значение.
Из всего этого следует, что нужно строку преобразовать в число. С чем успешно справляется `StrToInt`. А на случай некорректного ввода можно использовать `StrToIntDef`, где вторым параметром передается значение, которое функция вернет в случае некорректной строки.

```
const
  MAX_VALUE: Integer = ???; // Максимальный индекс Dict[]
...
for j:=0 to len-1 do 
  Pass:=Pass+Dict[Random(StrToIntDef(Edit1.Text, MAX_VALUE))+1];
```

Comment: Благодарна за помощь. Вопросы задаю по мере возникновения, основную часть разбираю сама. А вот с чем не могу справится, спрашиваю.

Comment: @Татьяна, я о том, что аналогичный вопрос Вы задали несколько дней назад и получили аналогичный ответ с теми же пояснениями https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/828752/283852

Comment: F.I.N, Да, но я просто постоянно упускала параметр: MAX_VALUE