# Как вставить значение из Edit вместо числа в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Как в этом коде, числа 2000, 01, 01 - заменить на значения из Edit1, Edit2, Edit3

```
Data := EncodeDate(2000, 01, 01);
```

Comment: "2000, 01, 01" - кхм, это ж три числа, не?

Comment: @Igor, Изменила вопрос - посмотрите.

Comment: Откройте для себя `TDatetimePicker`

Comment: Задавали же вы уже 2 таких же вопроса ..

Comment: Почему вы не желаете применять уже полученные ответы к точно таким же задачам? Этот вопрос ничем, абсолютно ничем не отличается от https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828730/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-edit-delphi/828752#828752 где именно вы опубликовали правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Data:= EncodeDate(StrToInt(Edit1.Text), StrToInt(Edit2.Text), StrToInt(Edit3.Text));
...
```